# Purpose of webdriver manager

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If webdriver manager is imported into our selenium code
(from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager),
then it is not required that we need to keep updating the browser drivers like chromedriver,geckodriver,...
will it keep upgrading itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when we use `webdriver_manager`, it helps manage the browser drivers automatically, eliminating the need for manual updates.

The `webdriver_manager` library, such as `ChromeDriverManager` as you mentioned, provides a convenient way to install and manage browser drivers. It downloads the appropriate driver executable for the specified browser version and operating system.

The advantage of using `webdriver_manager` is that it can automatically check the latest version of the browser driver and download the corresponding version if needed. This ensures that your code works with the latest browser and driver versions without requiring manual intervention.

Using `webdriver_manager` in your code simplifies the process of managing browser drivers and ensures compatibility between your code and the browser being used.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
Sir,can u explain this part?

Comment: Even if you have already installed the `webdriver_manager` package using pip, including this statement in your code is necessary to ensure that the correct version of the `ChromeDriver` is downloaded and installed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is specific to the use of `WebDriverManager`, would like to highlight about selenium's new feature. Starting from selenium `v4.6.0` and onwards, selenium has an in-built feature known as `SeleniumManager`, which essentially is similar to if not same as `WebDrivermanager`.

In other words, if you are using selenium `v4.6.0` or above, you don't need a third party library(`webdrivermanager`) to handle your driver and browsers. Selenium can do it by itself.

Refer the code comparison below:

1. Without using `WebDriverManager` and setting the `driver.exe` path manually:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/")
```

2. Using `WebDriverManager`:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/")
```

3. Using latest selenium(`v4.6.0` or above):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/")
```

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76388632/7598774
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Comment: So In the latest version of selenium, it keeps checking for the updates automatically and downloads without human intervention ,I have selenium 4.9,so it enough to have this line of code alone,driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: Yes, that's correct.