# Scrolling using Selenium(4.10.0)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scroll a table on a [website](https://alnair.ae/app/view/1412/3386/apartment/apartments)
I need to scroll because the information in the table is loaded dynamically.

If I try the `send_keys(Keys.END)` method, the element not interactable error is returned.

Or `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` - noting

Or `ActionChains(driver)` - nothing

Tried selecting different elements and classes and tags and XPATHs, CSS_SELECTORs

Python 3.8, Selenium(4.10.0)

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ES
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as WDW
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

self.URL_alnair = 'https://alnair.ae/app/view/1412/3386/apartment/apartments'
o = Options()
o.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
o.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_driver_path = r"YOUR PATH"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=o,service=ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path))

def get_data():
    driver.get(self.URL_alnair)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)
    
    element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._tr_18734_1')
    action.move_to_element(element[2])


def get_data():
    driver.get(self.URL_alnair)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)") # tried "document.body.scrollHeight", #"window.scrollBy(0, 200)", element.scrollTop = 500... etc


def get_data():
    driver.get(self.URL_alnair)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)
    
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)

    element = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._tr_18734_1')
    action.move_to_element(element[2]).perform()
    sleep(1)
    action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform() #
```

The above describes several code functions that I have tried in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you may try:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


URL_alnair = 'https://alnair.ae/app/view/1412/3386/apartment/apartments'
o = Options()
o.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
o.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=o)

def get_data():
    driver.get(URL_alnair)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)

    scroll_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="_scrollContainer_"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", scroll_bar)

get_data()
```

Things to note:

- You first need to find/locate the scrollbar which is embedded in the HTML page.
- The web-element `<div class="_scrollContainer_1ah3s_14">` represents the scrollbar which can be located using [Selenium WebDriver Finding Element by Partial Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049514/selenium-webdriver-finding-element-by-partial-class-name/56844649#56844649):

  ```
  scroll_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="_scrollContainer_"]')
  ```
- Once we find the web element for the scrollbar, simply can scroll down to its height:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", scroll_bar)
  ```

You may also try using [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

[Purpose of webdriver manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453996/purpose-of-webdriver-manager/76454059#76454059)