# using selenium with webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

error while using Selenium webdriver on python

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

same error is getting for both-'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

can anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `Service()` class along with `ChromeDriverManager().install()`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

and you'll need to install

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver-manager
```

reference:

- [Purpose of webdriver manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453996/purpose-of-webdriver-manager/76454059#76454059)
- https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium version `4.6.0` or higher, you do not really need `WebDriverManager` as selenium has an in-built tool known as `SeleniumManager` which does what `WDM` used to do.

Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774