I am trying to webscrape with selenium, but when I run my code, webdriver gives me a long error
Everytime I run this code on any device (I tried on my Mac and Windows)
from selenium import webdriver

PATH="/Users/priyanshulal/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/chromedriver-mac-arm64"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.chess.com/")

driver.close()

it gives me the same error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/priyanshulal/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/PersonalProject/selen/selen.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 56, in _binary_paths
    browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I am new to coding, so I'm not exactly sure what went wrong.
I expected a window for Chess.com with Google Chrome to pop up then close, but I got an error instead.

Please, give us the whole stacktrace. The error is not being displayed in the first lines of the error.

Hi Priyanshu, welcome to stack overflow. Top tip for coding: read the error. Check the exception thrown. That tells you what went wrong and is the best clue on how to fix it.  You've pasted the stack trace but not the exception. .. Looking at what you did paste you failed on this line driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) and inside that it failed finder.get_browser_path ... Those words tell me your PATH is incorrect. At a glance, Check things like ~ in the file path

The easiest and simplest way to avoid this issue is to use the webdriver_manager library.
You can understand the purpose and benefits and how to use this in the reference below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248102/11179336
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76857381/11179336

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.chess.com/")

driver.close()


This is unnecessary in up-to-date versions of selenium

Selenium has it's own built-in browser driver manager now. There's no need for this any more. See SIGHUP's answer.

With modern selenium there is no need to manage the driver installation in code.
Your code could simply be:
from selenium import webdriver

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.chess.com/")

